# how can i loop over all the die in the array and roll each one java

Tags: java, arrays, dice

So I have to create a program that makes "x" amount of die depending on user input. Then the user chooses how many faces the die have. I've succesfully figured out how to roll the die in the array. The `DieCollection`  object holds a set of `Die` objects in an array. The number of sides on each die is specified by passing an array of integers to the `DiceCollection` construtor.

So what I can't figuire out is how to take those rolled die numbers and add them up. The method I'm talking about is `getcurrentSum();` This is what I got so far. Would love it if someone could steer me in the right direction.

```
public class Die {
    private int currentSide;
    public static int Sides;

    public Die (int sides){
        Die.Sides = sides;
    }

    public  int currentSide(){        
        return currentSide;
    }

    public  void roll (){ 
        currentSide = (int)(Die.Sides *Math.random()) + 1;
    }
}

public class DieCollection {
    public void rollDice() {
        for (int xy = 0; xy< x.length; xy++) {
            Die dd = new Die(x[xy]);
            dd.roll();
        }
    }

    public void rollandshowDice() {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < x.length; xx++) {
            Die dd = new Die(x[xx]);
            dd.roll();
            System.out.println(dd.currentSide());
        }
    }

    public int getcurrentSum() {
        int sum = 0;
        Die dd = new Die(Die.Sides);
        for (int xz = 0; xz< x.length; xz++) {
            dd.roll();
            sum = x[xz] + sum;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**edit1:**

I've made some changed to the `getcurrentSum` to go through each array index and roll that dice, then add them up. This is the code, it still doesn't work unfortunately.

```
public int getcurrentSum() {  
    int sum = 0;

    for (int xz = 0; xz< x.length; xz++) {
        Die d1 = new Die(x.length);
        d1.roll();
        sum = x[xz] + sum;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `public static int Sides;` is going to be a problem - this means that EVERY `Die` you create will have the same number of sides - based on the last time the value was assigned

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: IMHO - `DieCllection` shouldn't be creating the `Die`, it should be passed an array of already created `Die`. You should, instead, inside your "sides" loop, create a `Die` and assign to an array which gets passed into the `DieCollection`

Comment: @JoeC Alright I took out all the irrelevant code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer unfortunately this is how I have to do it using the guidelines i was given.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Also good catch ill remove that static.

Comment: So the problem with naming variables with `x`, `xx`, `xy`, `xz`, `dd`, etc. is that nobody knows what they mean.  Start by giving them useful names, and then figure out where `x[xz]` is set.

Comment: @JoeC Ok dude thanks! That actullay helped alot. So i realized in my code x[xz] is basically the un-rolled dice. I gotta figuire out how i can loop over each index and roll it using the roll method. That's gonna be hard lol

Comment: You might want to [edit] that code into your question, as you can see, code in comments doesn't look good (and while doing so, indent the code correctly and remove extra spaces between lines, this will make the code readable)

Comment: @Frakcool Okay thanks, just did that.

Comment: See the edit I made and see how different your question looks now, that's what I was referring to

Answer (score 0):

As been told, you should have your `Die` model alone, make it have its own `roll` method and use its value to do the sum...

Then you could have an array / list that stores these `Die` objects and iterate over it getting its values to get the total sum.

For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DiceRoller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfDices = 5;
        int numberOfSides = 13;
        int currentSum = 0;

        List <Die> dices = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDices; i++) {
            Die die = new Die(numberOfSides);
            dices.add(die);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dices.size(); i++) {
            int roll = dices.get(i).rollDice();
            currentSum += roll;
            System.out.println(roll + "\t" + currentSum);
        }
    }
}

class Die {
    private int numberOfSides;
    private int currentSide;

    public Die(int numberOfSides) {
        this.numberOfSides = numberOfSides;
    }

    public int rollDice() {
        currentSide = (int)(numberOfSides * Math.random()) + 1;
        return currentSide;
    }

    public int getCurrentSide() {
        return currentSide;
    }
}
```

Here's what it prints in my machine:

```
2   2
6   8
2   10
9   19
2   21
```